# pygame running very slowly 12fps - Upgraded laptop

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, conda, frame-rate

I'm relatively new to using python have used pygame as a place to better understand how everything comes together.

I recently upgraded my laptop form a 2012 Macbook to the 2019.

Just wondering why the games I made on my 2012 are running soo much slower on my 2019 macbook. Managing packages with conda.

I don't know much but I suspect it may have to do with either

- The comp resolution upgrade (which I'm doubtful)
- method of installation of pygame

Initially, I Downloaded python3 with homebrew and then installed pygame (pygame would show a blank screen)
I then installed conda and managed packages through it.

I doubt it has to do with the way I have written it, I'm sure it's quite inefficient but I was achieving fps's of 60 for the same code.

If someone could guide me to where to find out more information It would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Profile it, then come back with actual code and the bottleneck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with how MacOS run Pygame. While your game is running, right-click it's icon in the Dock and select `Show in Finder`. Then in the Folder that shows up, you will see the Python Interpreter executable. Right-click it and click `Get Info`, and under `General` check the `Open in Low Resolution`.

Now your game should run fine. And no, Pygame's resolution will not be "Low".

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. This is something I could do with the python that I installed without miniconda3. The Python interpreter had the recognizable yellow and blue rocket and the option under general to lower the resolution. But the miniconda3 is a white shortcut file and doesn't have the option?

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by launching pygame in fullscreen. More of a workaround but a solution nonetheless.

Also if you do choose to do this be sure to create a key to exit the screen otherwise you'll need to restart your computer.